# Matrix operations with pyomo

Tags: pyomo

My objective function makes use of matrix multiplication, matrix power and eigenvalues. What system is there in place with pyomo to handle these?

For reference, I need to use this in the context of a Mixed Integer Non-Linear Problem. Thank you